# How to setup múltiple SSH configurations with Bitbucket and Git

Tags: git, ssh

I'm working with different projects using two different Bitbucket accounts. My SSH config file looks like this:

```
# account 1
Host bitbucket.org
    User user1
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_1

# account 2
Host bitbucket.org
    User user2
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_2
```

If I `git push` (or `pull` or whatever) to/from account 2, I get an error because it tries to connect using account 1 config.

I also tried this:

```
# account 1
Host account1
    HostName bitbucket.org
    User user1
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_1

# account 2
Host account2
    HostName bitbucket.org
    User user2
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_2
```

But I get the same error. How can I configure it so it tries with all the configurations until find the right one?

Comment: Isn't the user in both cases `git`?

Comment: Could you set up the same public key on both accounts?

Comment: @LinFelix Silly me! I replaced user git with user1/user2 in the remote URLs and it's working now. Post it as an answer and I will accept :)

Comment: @bruno Yes, you could. But that would be a terrible security practice. Two different user accounts should never share an SSH key.

Comment: @Nilpo: it's the same end-user, running on the same client machine, presumably using the same account on that machine. There's nothing wrong with using the same *public* SSH key on different machine and accounts, if the *private* key is indeed to be controlled by the same person.

Comment: What would be wrong is for the two private keys that can grant access to these different accounts (on BitBucket or other services) to be shared between multiple actual users.

Comment: @Bruno You should use different keypairs for each user and service. Using the same keypair becomes a real issue if the private key ever becomes compromised. A threat actor would immediately gain access to multiple services on multiple servers. The compromised user then must remember every single place it was used in order to go invalidate the key pair and all before anything malicious takes place without knowing where to look first. New key pairs for each user or service makes responding to an event very quick and easy. Each machine should use different keys for the same users as well.

Comment: @Nilpo if `~/.ssh/id_rsa_1` is compromised, the likelihood `~/.ssh/id_rsa_2` on the same machine is also compromised is generally pretty high...

Comment: @Bruno Disagree. That's only true if the entire machine is compromised. People send individual private keys by accident all the time. In 25+ years in the industry, I've never seen multiple keys compromised at the same time without an entire system being taken over. And that's rare. I see individual keys compromised on a regular basis.

Comment: Bitbucket (also GitHub and GitLab) will not allow the same public SSH key to be on multiple accounts - so this argument is not particularly relevant.

Comment: @Bruno What happens when a user loses a device? If you use a single key pair everywhere, when that key is invalidated on the server, the user will lose access to all servers from all remaining devices as well. A new keypair must be generated, applied to each device, and configured on the server(s). If the user IS the admin, the compromised key must remain active until this is completed. When using multiple key pairs as recommended, the admin invalidates a single key and nothing further needs to happen. The user continues with their other devices without losing access to any resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SSH config may not accomplish what you expect it to when connecting to the same host. You're better off bypassing that altogether. The better approach is to simply tell Git how you wish to connect and let it handle everything for you using the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` environment variable or the `core.sshCommand` config setting to supply the SSH command line for your repo to use. Full examples are found in this answer.

https://superuser.com/a/912281/98717

You should also double check your SSH settings. Generally, git repos are accessed by the `git` user.

Here's the text of the answer linked above as it exists at the time of this answer. Credit to the original user.

### Environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`

From Git version 2.3.0, you can use the environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` like this:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_example" git clone example
```

Note that `-i` can sometimes be overridden by your config file, in which case, you should give SSH an empty config file, like this:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_example -F /dev/null" git clone git@github.com:example/example.git
```

### Configuration `core.sshCommand`

**Since Git version 2.10.0**, you can configure this per repo or globally, using the `core.sshCommand` setting. There's no more need to use the environment variable. Here's how you clone a repo and set this configuration at the same time:

```
git clone -c "core.sshCommand=ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_example -F /dev/null" git@github.com:example/example.git
cd example/
git pull
git push
```

If the repo already exists, run:

```
git config core.sshCommand "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_example -F /dev/null"
```

The configuration is saved in `.git/config`

Comment: Why the down vote? This exactly answers the OP question. This is the correct method for supplying a user name or identity file to the git SSH connection.

Answer (score 0):

The second `~/.ssh/config` approach - the one where you have `Host account1` and `Host account2` - is usually easiest to work with once it's set up, but I didn't see anything in your post about actually *using* the new names in those repos. (Note that your first approach won't work: since the `Host` values are identical, it's impossible for the SSH client to know which one it should use in a given situation.)

For repos you already have, `git remote set-url origin account1:owner/repo` or `git remote set-url origin account2:owner/repo` will update the remotes to use the parameters defined in `~/.ssh/config`.

For repos you haven't cloned yet, instead of `git clone git@bitbucket.org:owner/repo`, use either `git clone account1:owner/repo` or `git clone account2:owner/repo`.

Once you've set the remote URLs as appropriate, then `git fetch`, `git pull`, `git push`, and any other network operations will use the parameters you've defined in `~/.ssh/config`. You won't have to change the commands, and if you need to change anything about the setup for one account (such as defining a new key or port) then you can do it once, for all affected repos, in `~/.ssh/config`.